# getting net::ERR_ABORTED after putting in jquery library source in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

So I'm trying to get an alert through jquery code. I have 3 inputs so login.password and button and when writing your login and password you should get an alert (log+pass). The error that i'm getting is:

> GET http://localhost/php5/jquery-3.3.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED.

Here is my code.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> PHP </title>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#send").click(function(){
                    var log=$("#login").val()
                    var pass=$("#password").val()

                    alert(log+pass)


                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="login" placeholder="Login"><br>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="button" id="send" value="send">
        <div class="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code working fine at my end :-https://prnt.sc/itr9sp. Seems like jQuery library file is not added properly at your end. it may be path issue. so try once with `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> `

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it works for me